# How can I fix the header of a table whose width is not fixed?

Tags: css

I have a table to which a user can add new columns. The width hence is not fixed. How can I fix the header for such a table?

I tried:

```
display:block
overflow-x:hidden
overflow-y:auto 
height:70%
```

in table body. It worked partially.

Comment: Tried setting custom width to your table's header ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (posting your HTML would help) you can nest a table inside the part that can be extended. You will be able to add as many columns (`<td>`) without effecting the table header.

```css
table td table td {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Add your fixed table header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>New Columns</td>
          <td>can be added</td>
          <td>without effecting your header</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```